# How to display the URL data in a POST Request using Express, Javascript & Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

How would I go about utilizing a `POST` request to display the `URL` data like a `GET` request? For example I'm trying to have the `URL` "http://localhost:8000/requestPost?hello=goodbye&numbers=123" print the following list  -

- hello - goodbye
- numbers - 123

How would I go about getting access to the `URL` variables with a `POST`? I'm using Express & Handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it the same way as you would for a get request:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/requestPost', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello: ' + req.query.hello + ' numbers: ' + req.query.numbers);
});

app.listen(3000);
```